# How to resolve the time difference b/w local server time and GMT time?

Tags: php, timezone

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
echo date('d-m-y  h:i:s',time());
-------------------------------------------
26-12-2012 03:07:48
```

At the same time GMT +05:30 from [here](http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/time-zone/asia/india/time/)

```
26-12-2012 03:12:25
```

It's giving some time difference in minutes, now i want to work with time ago function with local server time but local server is giving about -4 minutes from the GMT+05:30. How to resolve this issue?

Few days back i changed the server time as GMT+05:30 with the help of Admin, now again its giving the difference.

Comment: do not use `date_default_timezone_set()`  use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object if you need to work with several timezones

Comment: Perhaps your server time is off by 4 minutes?

Comment: @Salman A- yes off-course

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do here is run a cronjob every day/week which synchronizes the time of your server to a timeserver. You can easily do this with `ntpdate` command

http://www.bytechemist.com/2009/06/25/use-cron-and-ntpdate-to-keep-your-linux-servers-time-updated/